# MySql where..in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to implement the following query in MySql

```
SELECT name, value FROM opponent 
WHERE name in (SELECT name FROM noc WHERE fictive_status='fictional') 
AND value in (SELECT name FROM noc WHERE fictive_status='fictional')
```

I need to find all the rows in table opponent (name, value(some other name)) whose fictive_status (for both) in another table noc is 'fictional'.

Tried with

```
SELECT name, value from opponent WHERE(name,value) in (SELECT name FROM noc WHERE fictive_status='fictional')
```

which requires 2 columns for operand and

```
Select name, value from opponent where (name and value) in (select name from noc where fictive_status='fictional')
```

which returns me all the rows in the opponent table.

How can implement in a better way?

Comment: What is wrong with your original query?

Comment: It does not look right, isn't it? I'm querying table noc twice which are exactly the same. Can I query noc table once and use it for finding names and values from the opponent table?

Comment: Your query looks perfect to me. Straight-forward as it should be. You must look up the table twice; there is nothing wrong with it. MySQL was once very weak on `IN` clauses, and you'd use `EXISTS` clauses in order to circumvent this, but I guess this is a matter of the past. Both queries , with `IN` and `EXISTS` should result in the exact same execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using two subqueries like you do is inefficient because MySQL has to generate a large temporary table for each subquery, storing *ever* name from noc. It's a large temp table.

Instead, I suggest you use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name, o.value 
FROM opponent AS o 
JOIN noc AS n1 ON n1.fictive_status='fictional' AND n1.name = o.name
JOIN noc AS n2 ON n2.fictive_status='fictional' AND n2.name = o.value
```

If you have the right index on `noc(fictive_status, name)` then this will not be expensive. It won't scan the whole table, it will only search for matching rows.

The DISTINCT is to reduce the result set in the case where you have multiple matches in noc.

Answer (score 1):

Drum roll please . . . You can implement this in MySQL as:

```
SELECT o.name, o.value
FROM opponent o
WHERE o.name in (SELECT noc.name FROM noc WHERE noc.fictive_status = 'fictional') and
      o.value in (SELECT noc.name FROM noc WHERE noc.fictive_status = 'fictional');
```

This is actually your query with column aliases.  There is no *a priori* reason to change it.  The query uses ANSI standard SQL and should work in almost any database.

Comment: won't it be heavy to query noc twice for the exact same data?

Comment: @ShashankShekhar . . . Start with a working query.  Worry about optimization if the query is slow.  You can ask another question if that is your concern, because that is not mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following with `EXISTS`

```
 SELECT o.name, o.value 
    FROM opponent AS o 
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
      SELECT * FROM noc As n1 WHERE n1.name = o.name  AND n1.fictive_status='fictional'
    )
    AND EXISTS
    (
       SELECT * FROM noc As n1 WHERE n1.name = o.value   AND n1.fictive_status='fictional'
    )
```

Comment: how can n1.name be equal to o.name and also to o.value, that wont give any results

Comment: This is still not efficient enough. There are 2 subqueries that will generate 2 temp tables which I think will equally expensive as my original query. Join seems the answer.